# AS3 Keyboard Movement Error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im making a game and have written the code to move my sprite with the arrow keys. For some reason, these two errors pop up.

LINE 34
Warning: 1090: Migration Issue: The onKeyDown event handler is not triggered automatically by Flash Player at run time in Actionscribpt 3.0. You must first register this handler for the event using addEventListener ('keyDown' callback_handler).

LINE 39
Warning: 1090: Migration Issue: The onKeyUp event handler is not triggered automatically by Flash Player at run time in Actionscribpt 3.0. You must first register this handler for the event using addEventListener ('keyUp' callback_handler).

This is my code for the movement

```
stop();

import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

Wizard.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, KeyClick);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

var keys:Array = [];

function KeyClick(e:Event):void
{
    if (keys[Keyboard.RIGHT])
    {
        Wizard.x += 5;
    }
    if (keys[Keyboard.LEFT])
    {
        Wizard.x -= 5;
    }
    if (keys[Keyboard.UP]) 
    {
        Wizard.y -= 5;
    }
    if (keys[Keyboard.DOWN])
    {
        Wizard.y += 5;
    }
}

function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}

function onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
}
```

How do i fix these errors? Thanks :)

Comment: Voted down. Those are no errors and they don't stop your app from compiling, the compiler makes the effort to label them as warnings but still you can't seem to see them for what they are.

Answer (score 2):

Those are just warnings; the reason they're there is because in ActionScript 2, events worked like:

```
target.onKeyUp = function()
{
    //
}

target.onKeyDown = function()
{
    //
}
```

I assume the warnings are triggered because you've used the same naming convention for your handler functions as the old style of handling these events.

If they bother you, simply rename them to something else.